# change the TimeStamp return into mm:sec not hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this:

```
  <(Time.now).to_i>
```

it returns a integer thing 
and want to convert that integer value into (mins and seconds)
 only  as per my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Time.now.strftime("%M:%S")
```

Hope you are trying to find this

You can get the minutes and seconds by this

```
delta =  Time.now.to_i
    %w[ weeks days hours minutes seconds].collect do |step|
      seconds = 1.send(step)
      (delta / seconds).to_i.tap do
        delta %= seconds
      end
    end
```

It will return an array with having 5 elements . You can get the mins and secs from 
`arr[3]` and `arr[4]`

Also you can take the whatever the time in integer format as `delta` .

If you want to show only mins and secs when hr = 0

```
@hr = timedef[0]
@mn = timedef[1]
@sec = timedef[2]
time_remains = ''
unless self.timedef.blank?

  if @hr > 0

    time_remains = time_remains + "#{@hr} #{'hour'.pluralize(@hr)} "
  elsif @mn > 0
    time_remains = time_remains + "#{@mn} #{'minute'.pluralize(@mn)} and #{@sec} #{'second'.pluralize(@sec)} "
  else
    time_remains = time_remains + "#{@sec} #{'second'.pluralize(@sec)} "
  end
end
```

Comment: i have nothing do with (Time.now)     .. run this [<(Time.now).to_i>] at ur console and check wot it is returning... and i want that returned integer value into mins and secs

Comment: what r u exactly trying to search? do u  want a time difference to mins and secs ?

Comment: i did it by other way

Comment: now i have
t = [diff.divmod(60*60)[0], diff.divmod(60*60)[1].divmod(60)].flatten!
 => [0, 24, 30] 
this is 24 mins and 30 secs ....
i want that if hour is 0 it is not visible and it shows mins only

Comment: ya i was talking about time difference .. its my bad i cannt explain it properly         But finally i have
diff=1470
t = [diff.divmod(60*60)[0], diff.divmod(60*60)[1].divmod(60)].flatten!
 => [0, 24, 30] 
this is 24 mins and 30 secs ....
i want that if hour is 0 it is not visible and it only shows mins

Comment: found a new way .. check this

Answer (score 0):

use strftime -- see this page http://www.dzone.com/snippets/date-time-format-ruby  it has the formats (though its similar to c/c++ and Java)

Also, you will likely want to do some research into timezone handling on the time class.  there is a function: in_time_zone  that can convert the timezone for you.  So typically you store the times or the times fetched are in UTC then you can dynamically change the timezone before you strftime.

Comment: this gmme a good exposure over date and time formats ...                                       thanks fo considering